# How to enable community partner user to create new Quotes? (as a part of Managed SBCPQ package)

Tags: cpq

I am trying to enable community partner user to create new Quotes and edit them (as a part of SBCPQ managed package)

I am able to create new Quotes from CRM users and see them when I switch to community partners but once clicked on Edit lines, an error is thrown saying-
Access denied

Answer (score 0):

Something to check would be that the Profile for the partner users has access to price books, as well as quotes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also please check permission on Product options and Product features object